# Match if a column from one file partially matches a column in another file then print columns from both files

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have 2 files in which the fields are comma separated-

```
aks@dev1:~$ cat dir.txt

/home/aks/cleanup,512

/home/aks/git,208

/home/aks/github,424


/home/aks/predirsize,216

/home/aks/sample,288004
```

```
aks@dev1:~$ cat config.txt

/home/aks/cleanup,1,7,2

/home/aks/sample/aks,1,2,1

/home/vbht/test_bkup,1,7,None
```

I need to lookup the 1st field of dir.txt in the 1st field of config.txt and if it matches completely or partially then print the 1st field of config.txt,2nd field of dir.txt, 2nd, 3rd and 4th field of config.txt.

Desired output -

```
/home/aks/cleanup,512,1,7,2

/home/aks/sample/aks,288004,1,2,1
```

Comment: Do your files really have empty lines? Should those be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` way:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{ if(/^$/){next} if(NR==FNR){f1[$1]=$2;} else{for(path in f1){ if($1 ~ path ){print $1,f1[path],$2,$3,$4}}}}' dir.txt config.txt 
/home/aks/cleanup,512,1,7,2
/home/aks/sample/aks,288004,1,2,1
```

And here's the same thing broken into multiple lines and explained. You can still copy/paste this directly into your terminal:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
 { 
    ## Skip empty lines
    if(/^$/){ next } 

    ## If this is the first file, store the first field 
    ## as a key and the second field as its value in the 
    ##associative array f1 
    if(NR==FNR){ f1[$1]=$2 } 

    ## If this is the second file
    else{
        ## for each of the keys in f1, the paths
        for(path in f1){ 
            ## If the 1st field of this line matches a path
            if($1 ~ path){
                ## print all the things
                print $1,f1[path],$2,$3,$4
            }
        }
    }
 }' dir.txt config.txt
```